# Lat-Lng to geom in PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a table with lat-lng details. I need to add a geom point to it to plot the same in QGIS. I have added the below code in SQL - PostreSQL.

```sql
ALTER TABLE "complete_details" ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 3857);
UPDATE "complete_details" SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), 3857);
```

In the table `complete_details` LONGITUDE is 75.3729 and LATITUDE is 15.8816. If you check in google map this is in India, but when you plot using geom in QGIS the point is in Gulf of Guinea. Geom calculated in PostgreSQL is `0101000020110F00006B2BF697DDD75240A54E401361C32F40`.

Comment: Yes, the point you are talking about is known as "null island". Your problem is that 3857 (Web Mercator) is projected and in meters, whereas lat/lon, which is in degrees, using the code 4326. So, if you encode lat/lon as 3857, it will appear in null island, ie, very near the point 0,0. If I had 1 dollar for every time I have answered this question, I would be very rich now :-)

Comment: You can fix your problem by using ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Makepoint(lon, lat), 4326), 3857));

Comment: I deleted the column geom and then changed the code to => UPDATE "complete_pss_details" SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), 4326); but still the same issue shows up.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use WGS84 for lat long, so EPGS:4326. 3857 is web mercator.

```
ALTER TABLE "complete_details" ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);
UPDATE "complete_details" SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), 4326);
```

Comment: I changed it, it still shows in the same position. I even tried with new connection in QGIS.

Comment: I restarted QGIS, it started to work. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @DPK glad to hear that helped. If this answer was the solution please select it as correct, by ticking the green tick next to the answer.